# Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host after reboot

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm running apache2 on a CentOS 6.7 VM. My PHP website was working fine before a reboot but afterwards I'm getting 504 Gateway Timeout.

```
$ telnet <MYIP> 80
Trying <MYIP>...
Connected to <MYHOSTNAME>.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.0 504 Gateway Timeout

Gateway Timeout: can't connect to remote host
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I've been googling for hours but can't find anything that works. The website works locally i.e. if I wget http://localhost:80/.

My iptables is as follows:

```
$ sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1556/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35443               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1578/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1745/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1782/postmaster
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1866/master
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      2736/java
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      2736/java
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      1556/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      2854/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      2736/java
tcp        0      0 :::54644                    :::*                        LISTEN      1578/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1745/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:5432                    :::*                        LISTEN      1782/postmaster
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      1866/master
    enter code here
```

Any ideas what could be wrong or how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

After having restarted apache many times and trying to set firewall rules again I did both again and it worked.

I've no clue what the issue was so still interested if anyone knows.